# Trying to add Crashlytics in Android Studio (could not find method...)

Tags: android, crashlytics, google-fabric

I try to add Crashlytics to my project but Gradle is not syncing well.

```
This is my build.gradle:
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        // These docs use an open ended version so that our plugin
        // can be updated quickly in response to Android tooling updates

        // We recommend changing it to the latest version from our changelog:
        // https://docs.fabric.io/android/changelog.html#fabric-gradle-plugin
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.26.1'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.smartvibes.smartbeat"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}



dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.4.1'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okio:okio:1.7.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'org.florescu.android.rangeseekbar:rangeseekbar-library:0.4.0'
    implementation 'org.osmdroid:osmdroid-android:6.0.3'
    implementation 'io.nlopez.smartlocation:library:3.3.3'
    implementation 'io.nlopez.smartlocation:rx:3.3.3'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.0.3'
    implementation 'com.github.MikeOrtiz:TouchImageView:1.4.0'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.9.0'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton.rxbinding:rxbinding:0.4.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.9.0'
    implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.9@aar' {
        transitive = true;
    }
}
```

This is what I added in my manifest:

```
<meta-data
            android:name="io.fabric.ApiKey"
            android:value="my key"
            />
```

I manually changed

```
compile ('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.9@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
```

To

```
implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.9@aar' {
        transitive = true;
    }
```

Because compile is not supported anymore.

The error when I try to sync it is:
ERROR: Could not find method com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.9@aar() for arguments [build_ebny41u4h7onhh3ybv447hi4b$_run_closure3$_closure8@7d0b1f54] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.
Open File

I Googled on this issue but could not find an appropriate solution.
Anyone knows how to deal with this?

Comment: This is just a suggestion; Fabric Crashlytics is moving to Firebase Crashlytics from this year-end. Read this -  https://get.fabric.io/roadmap?utm_campaign=discover&utm_medium=natural
You might want to use Firebase Crashlytics instead. Firebase Crashlytics - https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are almost there. Just need to write this with ( ) :

```
implementation ('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.9@aar') {
    transitive = true;
}
```

Comment: I did this and it now raises a new error: WARNING: API 'variant.getExternalNativeBuildTasks()' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'variant.getExternalNativeBuildProviders()'.

Comment: It's warning and as per https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/issues/198 can be ignored.